# How do I add verticallayout to a bordercontainer on runtime?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I'm creating a bordercontainer on runtime:

```
var bcArtist:BorderContainer = new BorderContainer();
var imgArtist:Image = new Image();
var lblArtist:String = new String();
bcArtist.id = artistXML.pk_artist_id;
bcArtist.width = 75;
bcArtist.layout = VerticalLayout;
```

But the last line gives this error:

> 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Class to an unrelated type spark.layouts.supportClasses:LayoutBase.

I feel it is something very easy, but haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `layout` property accepts an *object* of type `LayoutBase` but you are giving it the class itself. Try:

```
bcArtist.layout = new VerticalLayout();
```

Answer (score 2):

`VerticalLayout` is the class. You need to create an instance of it.

```
bcArtist.layout = new VerticalLayout();
```